Using different hierarchical features for training and prediction
Im creating a recommender system that takes in customer data(ids and 5 features) and product data(ids and 1 feature). It predicts the revenue for each product from a given customer. The product hierarchy goes category, segment, family in order of granularity. I found that if I train embeddings using the segment as input but then predict using family I get better results every time on an unseen test dataset. It works but it feels wrong. Is this an acceptable practice?
